# File not showing in git lfs ls-files in spite of showing up in objects to be committed

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have cloned a repo with a bunch of files tracked with git lfs.
I had updated the .gitattributes using `git lfs track` to include the file I was about to add.
I have committed the .gitattributes, then added my new file.

When I try `git lfs status` I see my file in "Objects to be committed". However, when I type `git lfs ls-files`, the file is not there.

I have tried checking after committing the file, retrospectively adding it with `migrate` and some other combinations, all to no avail. The file does not appear to be tracked by LFS.

What am I missing? How to properly add a tarball to a repo to be tracked with lfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...I did not do `git lfs install` before adding files to the tree.

You need to have git LFS installed (for ex. through [downloading it from the official site](https://git-lfs.github.com/)), *but also* you need to run `git lfs install` in your repository to have LFS initialized there.